# Multisite Domain Mapping wp-admin login loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, cookies

I am trying to setup my multitsite with unique domains for each site.
What Ive been trying:
create the multisite with the specified config an .htaccess
create sites (tried sub-domain & directory)
test the sites work (they do)
change the Site Address (URL) to the needed domain
test the domain works perfect
test the wp-admin dashboard
this then starts the reauth login loop

if I login to the reauth link im stuck in the loop, if I change the url to wp-login then the correct cookie is created and login works until the cookie expires.

I have tried every proposed fix I have found in a whole weekend of searching:
`define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );`, 
`define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );`
and many many more
none of them make any difference.

Only theme is 2016, no plugins etc etc

The problem is obviously cookies but I don’t know where to start, to see why.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem. this solution worked for me on:

- wordpress 4.7.3
- multisite (sub directory) network
- native domain mapping (no plugin)

solution:
add the following to the wp-config.php file

```
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . 'wp-admin' );
```

right beneath the /* Multisite */ configurations

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'website.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . 'wp-admin' );
```

i found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/MikeNGarrett/e20d77ca8ba4ae62adf5

Comment: Doesn't works for me. I cannot login when this line existing in my wp-config.php file.